# Как одним регулярным вырежением выбрать определенные значения?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть текст вида:

```
Текст1|<ul><li>Тоже много текста</li></ul>Текст2|<ul><li>Снова много текста</li></ul>Текст3|<table border='1'><tr><td>Опять текст</td></tr></table>
```

Как одним регулярным вырежением выбрать только: **Текст1|, Текст2|, Текст3|**? Никаких дополнительных разделителей между этими "заголовками" нет.
Написал так:    `preg_match_all("/[А-Яа-я ]+\|/", $text);`  
Результат:

```
[0] => Array (  
        [0] => кст1|  
        [1] => т2|  
        [2] => ст3|  
        [3] => екст4|  
     )
```

Почему обрезается по половине слова?

Comment: @alexandernoa, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если исходный текст именно таков, я бы порекомендовал прибить все теги простейшим способом:

```
s/<\/?.+?>/ /g
```

Answer (score 0):

'>' в начале каждой подстроки не учитывается, поэтому результат глючный.